# Google drive picker - select document with angular 2

Tags: angular

when I use [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) with Angular 2 everything seems ok but I get a cross-origin error every time. I work on locale with address http://localhost:5555. And i use jetty server, java at backend. Could someone tell me what to do and what I miss? I see the cross-origin problem is a general issue but I could not find a solution yet.

After a little search i find solution, i comes from css issue. picker object is created in body but not shown as modal.
Solution:

```
.picker-dialog-bg {
    z-index: 20000 !important;
}

.picker-dialog {
    z-index: 20001 !important;
} 

.picker-dialog-content {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I see there is no comment yet. Maybe another approach solves my problem. Is there any sugestion about out of box script  using google picker with angular 2, there is a module with angular 1 but i do not see for angular 2.

Comment: i find the solution after a lot work. it stems from css issue. picker div is created in html body but not shown. so adding a few line css we can show it as modal. there were solutions for it,
( thanks to cs-NET and felipemarin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616810/show-google-picker-inside-over-modal, https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/619) but they are missing, combining solutions it solve my problem:.picker-dialog-bg {
    z-index: 20000 !important;
}

.picker-dialog {
    z-index: 20001 !important;
}

Comment: Note: the 'cross-origin' alert occurs in console but drive picker runs after adding css files above